# c# custom DbUpdateException

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I'm building a wpf application with a database in entity framework code first.

I allow the user to delete items in database, but when item is linked to other data, an exception will be thrown.

This is what I had originally

```
try
{
  //delete item
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
}
```

This is working, but the message displayed isn't so much user firendly. So I tried to create a `custom exception`

```
public class CustomException : Exception
{
    public CustomException (string Message)
    {
        Message = "Item can't be deleted";
    }
}
```

And I've modified my catch

```
catch (CustomException ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
}
```

But this is not showing the `messagebox` with my message, but it's stopping my application for a DbUpdateException.

Is there a way to customize the message for this type of exception?

Comment: You can just catch a `DbUpdateException` and throw a `CustomException ` if thats what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the catch won't change how the framework throws an exception.  You should just catch the `DbUpdateException` and show a message that is appropriate:

```
catch (DbUpdateException ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show("item can't be deleted");
}
```

Comment: It was really simple after all. Thanks :)